# Reset Storyboard animation in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

I hv a `ListBox` in my application with number of items. I m animating `ListBoxItem` using following code

```
var blinkStoryboard = new Storyboard
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
        };                       
            var currentFence = GPSData.lstRouteDetail.Where(x => x.ID == stationID).FirstOrDefault();
            ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(routeList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(stationID));//.ContainerFromIndex(i));


            ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);
            DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
            Ellipse target = (Ellipse)myDataTemplate.FindName("sa", myContentPresenter);
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

            // Describes the brush's color using RGB values. 
            // Each value has a range of 0-255.
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 0);
            target.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

            var blinkAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))));
            blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))));


            Storyboard.SetTarget(blinkAnimation, target);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(myListBoxItem, stationID.ToString());

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blinkAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

            blinkStoryboard.Children.Add(blinkAnimation);            
           blinkStoryboard.Begin();
```

I need to animate only one item at a time. In my case when i m adding animation to second item, animation not removing from first item.

How to remove animation from previous item, before animation second item ?

[image]
[image]